# Adding a nullable foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have two tables built like this (this is just a simplified and non-proprietary example):

```
Person Table
-----------
p_Id, f_name, l_name

Job Table
----------
job_Id, job_desc
```

I want to add a foreign key column, Persons.job_Id, that can be nullable that references Job.job_Id (the PK) The reason is, the job may not be known in advance, so it could be null. Having an "Other" is not an option.

I had this so far but I'm getting "could not create constraint".

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person  
ADD job_Id INT FOREIGN KEY (job_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Job(job_Id)
```

Comment: Do the data types of the 2 columns match?

Comment: They need to.Job_Id is an Identity column of sequential ints.

Comment: Anyone care to say why they downvoted so I can either change the question to make it better and/or learn from my mistake?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try it in two steps:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD job_Id INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD CONSTRAINT FL_JOB 
FOREIGN KEY (job_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Job(job_Id);
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD job_Id INT NULL,CONSTRAINT FL_JOB FOREIGN KEY (job_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Job(job_Id);` works too to do it in one statement.

Comment: @MartinSmith : right, i'm a bit old school in these things and really like to do them one at a time, but his a very good to do it too.

Comment: So, I created the Job table originally and then had to recreate it. When I recreated it, I forgot to create the primary key...dammit. Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 14):

Try it like this, WITH NOCHECK:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD job_Id INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FL_JOB 
FOREIGN KEY (job_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Job(job_Id);
```

Comment: WITH NOCHECK helps when Foreign Key could be NULL

Comment: Looking at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1338565/755977), it seems that there could be performance side effects. Is this mandatory?

Comment: Is this a good idea?  I read that it allows values that are not in the referenced table.

Comment: I think it allows only NULL, not other values, that are not in the references table..

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work in latest version:

giving you the example for `profile` table and Foreign Key `user_id`

> ALTER TABLE `profile` CHANGE `user_id`
> `user_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Answer (score -3):

Below is my solution with creating foreign key programmatically.
TestTable1 has substitute of FK that is either NULL or matches record in TestTable2.
TestTable2 has standard FK in TestTable1.

```
CREATE Table TestTable1 (ID1 int IDENTITY UNIQUE, ID2 int NULL);
GO
CREATE Table TestTable2 (ID2 int IDENTITY UNIQUE, ID1 int NOT NULL foreign key references TestTable1(ID1));
GO
CREATE procedure CreateTestRecord1 @ID2 int null AS
begin
    if @iD2 IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from TestTable2 where ID2 = @ID2)
    begin
        RAISERROR('Cannot insert TestTable1 record. TestTable2 record with ID %d doesnt exist', 16, 1, @ID2);
        return;
    end
    Insert into TestTable1(ID2) OUTPUT Inserted.ID1 Values(@ID2);
end
GO
CREATE procedure LinkTable1toTable2 @ID1 int, @ID2 int NULL as
begin
    if @iD2 IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from TestTable2 where ID2 = @ID2)
    begin
        RAISERROR('Cannot update ID2 in TestTable1 record. TestTable2 record with ID %d doesnt exist', 16, 1, @ID2);
        return;
    end
    update TestTable1 Set ID2=@ID2 where ID1=@ID1;
    select @@ROWCOUNT;
endGO
```