# I have a datawarehouse problem with the fact and dimension table

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, dimensions, fact

I have a dimensions table invoices and a fact table

I can see my invoices in dimension invoice but it won't show up in the Fact table. The Fact table is connected to the dimensions table invoice with a foreign key invoice_id. But it's still not showing me the invoice

How can I fix this problem? Can someone help?

Thank you

```
SELECT [Id] ,[Land] ,[Firm] ,[Magazijn] ,[year] ,[Invoice number] ,[Checksum] ,[LastModifiedDate] 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Invoices] 
where Invoice number = 6451847
```

Here is get no invoice for this number

```
SELECT [Id] ,[Invoice_id],[Land] ,[Firm] ,[Magazijn] ,[year] ,[Invoice number] ,[Invoice_Date] ,[LastModifiedDate] 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[FACT] 
where Invoice number = 6451847
```

Here it shows the invoice number (note Invoice_ID is the FK)

Comment: Where is it "not showing"? Please post the SQL query that you are using or describe how you are doing it. I suggest you take sample failing record and inspect the values in the join columns. One reason for this may be that the value is NULL in the fact table (foreign keys allow this)

Comment: SELECT [Id]
      ,[Land]
      ,[Firm]
      ,[Magazijn]
      ,[year]
      ,[Invoice number]
      ,[Checksum]
      ,[LastModifiedDate]
  FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Invoices]
where Invoice number = 6451847

Here is get no invoice for this number



SELECT [Id]
      ,[Invoice_id] ==> (FK)
       ,[Land]
      ,[Firm]
      ,[Magazijn]
      ,[year]
      ,[Invoice number]
      ,[Invoice_Date]
       ,[LastModifiedDate]
  FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[FACT]
where Invoice number = 6451847


Here it shows the invoice number

Comment: I have edited your question and added this code. It seems like you're asking how can this be if this is a foreign key? First thing to do is check if the FK is turned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253623/how-to-list-out-all-foreign-keys-with-with-nocheck-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this:

I am not sure why you have the fields in the fact table that you do as they are duplicated in the dimension. What are your measures?

```
SELECT ft.[Id] 
, ft.[Invoice_id]
, ft.[Land] 
, ft.[Firm] 
, ft.[Magazijn]
, ft.[year] 
, ft.[Invoice number] 
, ft.[Invoice_Date]
, ft.[LastModifiedDate]
, iv.[Id] 
, iv.[Land] 
, iv.[Firm]
, iv.[Magazijn]
, iv.[year] 
, iv.[Invoice number] 
, iv.[Checksum] 
, iv.[LastModifiedDate] 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[FACT] ft
JOIN [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Invoices] iv ON iv.id = ft.Invoice_id
where iv.[Invoice number] = 6451847
```